# how to change the font size using jquery from the dropdown list

Tags: jquery

```html
<div class="card">
  <div id="name" class="badge">
    <div id="address" class="badge">
    </div>
    <select id="font-size">
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="14">14</option>
      <option value="18">18</option>
    </select>
```

I have the main div with class "card" which has many other divs inside. I want to change the div's font size from the dropdown.

jQuery code is:

```js
$(".badge").click(function(){
    var id = this.id;//get clicked id

    $("#font-size").change(function(){
       $("#"+id).css('font-size', $(this).val()+"px");//change font according to the clicked element
    });
});
```

My problem is that when first div (name) is clicked everything works fine. But when the second div is clicked then first is also bound. And font size is changed for both. I want the font size to change independently according to the div clicked.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change font size when clicking a div

```
$(".badge").click(function(){
   var id = this.id;//get clicked id

   $("#"+id).css('font-size', $('#font-size').val()+"px");
});
```

What you were doing was attach an event handler to the select every time you cliked on a div.

This code changes the font size of the clicked dive to the value selected in the combobox when you click the div. look here http://jsfiddle.net/s55Dy/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var id;

$(".badge").click(function(){
   id = this.id;
});

$("#font-size").change(function(){
   if (id) $("#"+id).css('font-size', $(this).val()+"px");
});
```